# getting array elements missing a key with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json array

```
[
{
"k1":"n1",
"k2":[
      {"a1":"v1",
       "a2":[{"b1":"v11"},...],
        "a3":"v3",...},
       {"a1":"v12",
        "a3":"v32",...},
       
     ],
     ...
},
{
"k1":"n2",
 "k2":[
      {"a1":"v1",
        "a3":"v3",...}
     ],
...
},
{
"k1":"n2",
 "k3":[
      {"s1":"v1",
        "s3":"v3",...},
      ...
   ]
},
...
]
```

I would like to use jq to get all the elements where the key `k2` exists and just return the array elements of `k2` that dont have the subkey `"a2"`. So for the example above I would like to return

```
[
{
"k1":"n1",
"k2":[         
       {"a1":"v12",
        "a3":"v32",...},
       
     ],
},
...
]
```

(in the first element, only the first element of k2 has the subkey a2 so thats the only one I removed, the 2nd element has `k2` but k2 doesnt have any elements with `a2` and the 3rd element doesnt have `k2`)

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  It would not be so difficult to give at least one simple example based on valid JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter using `select` and `has`, adjust the output using `map`.

```sh
jq 'map(
  select(has("k2") and any(.k2[]; has("a2")))
  | .k2 |= map(select(has("a2") | not))
)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "k1": "n1",
    "k2": [
      {
        "a1": "v12",
        "a3": "v32"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LhRZiz7FVy)

Comment: The `select(has("k2") and any(.k2[]; has("a2")))` will only pick elements where k2 has items with the subkey a2? Shouldnt be just `select(has("k2"))`?

Comment: @user35202 There are two criteria an element from the outer array has to meet to be selected, and both have to be true (hence the use of `and` in between). Firstly, there has to be a field called `k2`, and secondly, from the items within the array in `k2` (`.k2[]`) there has to be at least one (`any`) that has a field called `a2`. Meeting the first deselects the third item (no `.k2`), meeting the second deselects the second (no `.a2` in `any` of the `.k2[]` items).

Comment: If all elements of the k2 array have a2 I will get `{
    "k1": "n1",
    "k2": []
      
  }`. Can I remove these (where k2 value is the empty array)?

Comment: @user35202 What do you want to be removed? Only the `k2` field (leaving you with `{"k1": "n1"}`), or the whole object (as with those where `k2` was not present)?

Comment: the whole object (as with those where k2 was not present)

Comment: @user35202 To remove it entirely, i.e. to not select it in the first place, add a third condition which is the opposite of the second (at least one that has **no** field called `a2`): `… and any(.k2[]; has("a2") | not)`